# How to access a variable in a singleton class used by a module in Play 2.5 scala

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I made a scheduler in Play Framework 2.5 using akka quartz (https://github.com/theatrus/akka-quartz)

Everything is good until I want to cancel a job
because I can't access the variable holding the Cancellable object.

Below is the code:

**This is for the module**

*RecurrentTaskModule.scala*

```
class RecurrentTaskModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
    override def configure() = {
        bindActor[WeatherHistoryApiActor]("weather-history-api-call")
        bind(classOf[RecurrentTask]).asEagerSingleton()
   }
}

@Singleton
class RecurrentTask @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, 
@Named("weather-history-api-call") val weatherHistoryApiActor: ActorRef,
lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, scheduleModel: TxScheduleModel) {
    var scheduleMap: Map[String, Cancellable] = _
    val f = quartzActor ? AddCronSchedule(actorRef,
                    "%d %s %s %s %s %s".format(0,"*","*","*","*","*",
                    Message(""),true)

  val r = Await.result(f, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[AddCronScheduleResult]
    r match {
        case AddCronScheduleSuccess(cancel: Cancellable) => {
            scheduleMap.put("%s".format(schedule._1), cancel)
        }
        case AddCronScheduleFailure(reason: Throwable) => {
        }
    }
}
```

**In my config**

*application.conf*

```
play.modules.enabled += "tasks.RecurrentTaskModule"
```

As you can see, if I can just access the

```
var scheduleMap
```

I can easily cancel the the job by calling the Cancellable object in the map

By the way, I want to access it in my Application.scala (controller)

Comment: Did you inject `RecurrentTask`  into your `Application` controller?

Comment: oh my god..... I just assumed you can't do that.. I thought module seems so special... ugghh.. can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject your `RecurrentTask` singleton into your controller instance:

`class Application @Inject() (recurrentTask: RecurrentTask) {`

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I just thought this is not possible because i tried it before but I think I inject RecurrentTaskModule instead.. @_@